# Best practices of passing array in url for GET API in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, api, laravel, laravel-5

I want to know the best practices for passing array in url and how can i define my routes for accepting that array in laravel 5 and pass it to the controller. Any Suggestions??

Let us take an example

URL - http://localhost/new/public/api/getaudit/

In this url, I want to pass array. Like: array('car','bike')
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything, yet?

Comment: use a standard get request with query parameters: `http://localhost/new/public/api/getaudit/?array=car&array=bike` To access, `$_GET['array']` or whatever wrapper laravel uses, something like `Request::get('array')`

Comment: @Steve: this `array=car&array=bike` will override one value with the other, so in `$_GET['array']`is just the value `bike`, you need `array[]=car&array[]=bike`

Comment: @swidmann oh yes, i forget that php does that (its a perfectly valid query string), amended: `http://localhost/new/public/api/getaudit/?array[]=car&array[]=bike`

Comment: In our project we solve exactly this problem (getting audit) with a POST and send an JSON-Array with IDs as body. It was our preferred solution instead of doing one get-Request per audit or using URL-params.

Comment: @steve if my array elements are at higher no of side.. Does it look suitable ?

Comment: @FaNtAMode Should be fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Comment: you could also jusy use comma seperated string and explode it yourself, to save a few chars: `/?array=car,bike` `$array = explode(',', $_GET['array'];`

Comment: @steve Thanks steve exactly what i was thinking :)